# Save tensorboard tf.summary.image without color transformations

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

According to doc images are normalized to fit in range [0,255]. My model sometimes generates dark images (in range x < 255, eg. [0, 200]). Such images are then converted to [0,255], so they are very bright. Only way to stop this is add 255 pixel in the corner of the image. Is there way to avoid this scaling in tensorboard? I am scaling everything myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an image batch in one of the `float[16,32,64]` dtypes that you are happy with the scale of simply cast it to `uint8` before doing the summary and the scale will be left alone.

```py
byte_image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
tf.summary.image(name=name, tensor=byte_image)
```

---

You might find it helpful for consistency to keep floating point images in `[0, 1)` and using the [`tf.image.convert_image_dtype`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype) function to go between different dtypes instead of `tf.cast`.